# How to use Qt designer form class and c++ class together properly in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, qt-designer

I have written a c++ program with `Qt` to make a ssh connection and take some information from remote system and executing command by opening a channel. I made a c++ class, with source and header and after that I made a `Qt designer form class` for testing my class.
 my constructor in the first class is like this:

```
info::info(const void* ip, const char* pw, const void* hostName)
{
    int a;
    _ip = ip;
    _password = pw;
    _hostName = hostName;
}
```

I want to set ip and password and host name in the main function or with ui(Qt designer form class). I wrote this in the main function and my program works fine:

```
info inf("localhost", "mypassword", "heydari.f");
```

I also tested with a remote machine and that was fine too. 
now I want to open my ui window and set ip and password and host name from there and take the needed information, like cpu speed for example. I wrote in main function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    info inf("localhost", "mypassword", "heydari.f");
    i2 j;
    j.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

when I run this code, parameters that I had passed to constructor changes and became nonsense and same thing every time. so my program doesn't work.
+I have made an object from my main class in my `Qt designer form class` to use of some functions and I guess the problem is there.
is there any reference to read or any advice that helps me to understand this contest and connections between these two classes?
shortly,I think my problem is in calling constructor two times. one in main function and other one is when making an object in `i2`. any idea??

Comment: Can you show us your code for i2 class?

Comment: Eh.. need a MRE by look of it you save pointer to a constant, you do not copy a string. something in your code may assume latter

Comment: `i2` is the `Qt designer form class`. which in its source file contains only slots for buttons and some other ui things.  in header file I defined my privates like this : info inf; and Ui::i2 *ui; info is my main class that I made at first. any specific thing to show? @RoyaGhasemzadeh

Comment: **_const void*_** nooo

Comment: I want to pass those objects to  `ssh_options_set` function. this function accepts const void* variables only. and anyway I think I didn't have any problem there. what's wrong with that? @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie emmm I didn't understand what you mean clearly. can you tell more?

Comment: I found my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964807/calling-constructor-of-a-class-in-another-class