# calling constructor of a class in another class

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, qwidget

I have two classes named info and i2 in qt. info is a `c++ class` and i2 is a `Qt designer from class`. I want to use i2 as an environment for testing my info class. 
 I included info.h in the header of i2.my info class has two constructor like below:

```
info();
info(const void *ip, const char* pw, const void *hostName);
```

now I want to make an object of info in i2 class and pass those three parameters( ip and pw and hostname) to info and use them in my program. like below:

```
private:
    Ui::i2 *ui;
    info inf("172.30.6.91", "mypw", "heydari.f");
```

this doesn't work . I got these errors:

```
/home/heydari.f/i1/i2.h:48: error: expected identifier before string constant
     info inf("172.30.6.91", "mypw", "heydari.f");
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and :

```
/home/heydari.f/i1/i2.h:48: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
```

my info class header :

```
#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

class info
{
private:

    ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    const void* _hostName;
    const void* _ip;
    const char* _password;

public:
    info();
    info(const void *ip, const char* pw, const void *hostName);
    ~info();
    //some another functions

};

#endif // INFO_H#ifndef KERNEL_H
```

my i2 class header:

```
#ifndef I2_H
#define I2_H
#include <QDialog>
#include "info.h"

namespace Ui {
class i2;
}

class i2 : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit i2(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~i2();

private slots:
//some push button functios

private:
    Ui::i2 *ui;
    info inf;

};

#endif // I2_H
```

Comment: Now, try naming you object something other than "inf", and see what happens.

Comment: no difference. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Make a [mcve] so we can see enough of the involved classes. Must `ui` be a pointer? Why not make it an automatic variable, `Ui::i2 ui;`?

Comment: I didn't declare `ui` as a pointer, it is Qt's default form. I mean Ididn't change that and always used it as it was. I will add some parts of my classes to the question. @TedLyngmo

Comment: Does `info inf{"172.30.6.91", "mypw", "heydari.f"};` work?

Comment: yeees.. thank so much, but why? @TedLyngmo

Comment: @fatemehheydari I made it an answer with a link to initialization info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [braced-init-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization):

```
info inf{"172.30.6.91", "mypw", "heydari.f"};
```